# Adding unique value in pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have many to many relationship of level and subjects.To add subjects in the subject table and levels in the level table i have a code below:

```
public function store(Request $request,Level $level)
{
    DB::transaction(function () use ($request, $level) {
        foreach ($request->get('subject') as $value) {
            $subject = Subject::find($value);
            if(is_null($subject)){
                $s = Subject::create(['name'=>$value]);
                $level->subjects()->attach($s->id);
            }
            else{
                $level->subjects()->attach($value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that i want to add the unique subject for a level in the pivot table.
Is there any solution i could unique subject for a particular level in pivot table?